# ATBSWP2 Chapter 8 Practice Project: How do I set timed input using the time module?

Tags: python

Hi this is my first time using this website so if I mess up the formatting please bear with me. I'm currently stuck at one of the practice projects in Chapter 8 and I can't seem to find any decent answers for this project.

This is the question:

**To see how much PyInputPlus is doing for you, try re-creating the multiplication quiz project on your own without importing it. This program will prompt the user with 10 multiplication questions, ranging from 0 × 0 to 9 × 9. You’ll need to implement the following features:

-If the user enters the correct answer, the program displays “Correct!” for 1 second and moves on to the next question.

-The user gets three tries to enter the correct answer before the program moves on to the next question.

-Eight seconds after first displaying the question, the question is marked as incorrect even if the user enters the correct answer after the 8-second limit.**

```
import random, time

num_of_ques = 10
tries = 3
correct_ans = 0
start_time = 0
elapsed = 0

for ques_num in range(num_of_ques):
    num1 = random.randint(0, 9)
    num2 = random.randint(0, 9)

    result = num1 * num2

    while tries > 0:
        if start_time == 0:
            start_time = time.time()

        while True:
            ans = input(f'{ques_num+1}: {num1} * {num2} = ? ')
            try:
                ans = int(ans)

                break
            except ValueError:
                print('Not a number, please try again.')

        elapsed = time.time() - start_time
        

        if ans == result and elapsed<=8:
            print('Correct!')
            correct_ans += 1
            time.sleep(1)
            break
        elif ans == result and elapsed>8:
            print("Time's up!")
            break
        else:
            print('Incorrect, try again!')
            tries -= 1
    ques_num += 1

time.sleep(1)
print('Score: %s / %s' % (correct_ans, num_of_ques))
```

I can't really seem to get the 8 second timer part correct. I'm also a complete beginner at python so I try to use the modules that are taught in the book. Are there any other places that I can put the (elapsed = time.time() - start_time) so the code works? Any help would be appreciated.
(using Python 3.9 btw)